# Visualize member count on a map

Tags: java, html, geolocation

I am building an online reservation system for a tennis club and I want to  visualize our member count on a map of Belgium with a count per district/village or city (whatever is possible).

How should I do this?

I thought using something like Google maps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Map Layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers). But then, it depends on what kind of data you have.

Comment: I have a table with the addresses of all our customers, so street with number, postal code and city. They all live in Belgium of course.

Comment: I suggest you look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers then. Group the data by city, look up the lat, long of the city, and add KML for your overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example use [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org) with [custom markers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Marker_API). The same functionality is provided by [google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/training/customizing/custom-markers).